# Convert string to conditional operator

Tags: string-manipulation, conditional, conversion

I have a RadioButtonBar with a selection

```
x = None;
{RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[x], {lt, le, eq, gt, ge}], Dynamic[x]}
```

Once a radio button is selected, I would like to convert the selection to a conditional operator, e.g., eq is ==. Then use the operator to select rows in a data table via Select. I have tried ToExpression and Symbol without much success. What are good ways to do this? I have not been able to find anything on the web to do this. There are warnings not to use eval as a general practice. Is that the way to go? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rules in  the second argument of `RadioButtonBar` to specify the values and labels for each button:

[image]

```
x = None;
t = 3;

{RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[x], 
   {Less -> lt, LessEqual -> le, Equal -> eq, Greater -> gt, GreaterEqual -> ge}], 
 Dynamic[x], 
 Dynamic @ Select[Range[10], x[#, t] &]} // Column
```

[image]

Note: From the title of your question you probably meant to make labels strings as in

```
RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[x], 
  {Less -> "lt", LessEqual -> "le", Equal -> "eq", Greater -> "gt", GreaterEqual -> "ge"}]
```